# POST value of key/value pair from the query string to BASE_DIR

Tags: php, post, get

I'm trying to post the value `1` of the key `user_id` from the following `url`

```
www.site.com/directory/subdirectory/test.php?file=test.doc&user_id=1
```

to define the base directory like,

```
$user= (isset($_REQUEST['user_id']));
define('BASE_DIR',"/home/user/public_html/directory/subdirectory/$user");
```

but the value of `$user` isn't being extracted in the base directory.

What's going wrong here? Any idea?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to a directory traversal attack.

Comment: @PeeHaa, what's the best alternative then? There are cases, when there are no alternatives available there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = isset($_REQUEST['user_id']) ? $_REQUEST['user_id'] : 0;
define('BASE_DIR',"/home/user/public_html/directory/subdirectory/$user");
```

Assign the user id value for `$user`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your putting in the base dir the boolean value of the expression ((isset($_REQUEST['user_id'])), not the value itself.

```
if((isset($_REQUEST['user_id']))
    $user = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
else
    $user = 0;

define('BASE_DIR',"/home/user/public_html/directory/subdirectory/" . $user);
```

Comment: boolean becomes positive if i post the value from `session variable` and i was driven by the same concept.

Comment: hmm, you could do something like (int)((isset($_REQUEST['user_id'])), but that would return just 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this

```
$user= isset($_REQUEST['user_id'])?$_REQUEST['user_id']:'';
```

and dont include files from urls,it is unsecured

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['user_id'])) {
  $user = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
  define('BASE_DIR',"/home/user/public_html/directory/subdirectory/".$user);
} else {
   $user = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid boolean in this case we can simply use

```
$user = $GET['user_id'];
```

A better approach for posting a numeric value from query string to `BASE_DIR` url or other inline urls is to trim the variable like,

```
$user = $_GET['user_id']);
$user = trim($user);
```

and then sanitize it with

`ctype_digit();` function

like,

```
if (ctype_digit($user)) {
//do somethisng
}else{
//do some other things.
```

In case of alphanumeric string value the above sanitization approach can be replaced with

`ctype_alnum();` function